# SQL Stored Procedure - Compare C# Dictionary to JSON

Tags: c#, sql, json, t-sql, table-valued-parameters

I have a C# dictionary object I would like to pass to an SQL stored procedure and compare its contents to a field containing JSON string.

```
Dictionary<String,Object> d = new Dictionary<String,Object>
d.Add("A",True);
d.Add("B",False);
```

Let's presume that the table content is as follows. Based on the above dictionary would mean that the stored procedure returns record #2.

```
ID        JSON
----------------------------------------
1         { "A": false, "B": false }
2         { "A": true, "B": false }
```

I am aware of something called TVP but have no idea how to implement this in SQL or how to parse JSON. How would I achieve this?

Comment: See following link.  Each function of the 4 functions on link has details and examples : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: have u considered serializing Dictionary into a string before passing into SP? thus you'll have a simple strings comparison